# ERROR when I try to instantiate a String[] object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read some information from a text file and put in a String[]
I read from the file succesfully, but when I try to put the information in the String[], I get this error :"object reference not set to an instance of an object". This is the code where I get the error:

```
string total = linie.Replace(idCont + "_" + rows["JOB"].ToString() + "_" + Loturi[i] + " : ", "")
Vol_Plicuri[i] = total.Split('|')[0].Trim();
```

I don't know how to get bypass this error.
Thanks!

Comment: `rows["JOB"]` is probably null.

Comment: there really isn't enough code here to help you... how does linie and Vol_Plicuri get declared? where does linie get its value set?

Comment: start by splitting up the parts on separate lines and figuring out which part is doing what you expect (perhaps only some of the times). [edit] I suspect @ken2k is right though.

Comment: no is not, because "total" has the correct value in it

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put a mbox befor the "Vol_Plicuri[i] = total.Split('|')[0].Trim();" and was not null.

Make sure that `Vol_Plicuri` is set to a non-null value.

Comment: I put a mbox befor the "Vol_Plicuri[i] = total.Split('|')[0].Trim();" and was not null.

Comment: There are more places where a `NPE` could be generated.

Comment: there are many reasons that might make this error occur, linie might be null or total don't have a "|" character

Comment: @XandrUu Then your `Vol_Plicuri` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect every variable in a debugger to see which is null.  If you find this difficult, breaking up complex lines into multiple simpler lines of code can make it easier. (Your stack trace will give you the line that errors, so if you do less per line there is less guessing in what failed.)  If certain values may actually legitimately be null, you may need to add in 'if not null' wrappers around such statements.